# Dynamically setting pointer to int giving incorrect size

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a `struct` defined:

```
struct Query {  
   int *pages;
   int currentpage;
};


struct Query *new = malloc(sizeof(struct Query));

new->pages = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
```

I then checked the size of `new->pages` to ensure that the size was 4 by doing:

```
    int size = sizeof(new->pages)/sizeof(new->pages[0]);
```

However, `size` keeps returning `2` as opposed to `4`.

Would anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sizeof(new->pages)/sizeof(new->pages[0])` meant `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`

Comment: `pages` is a `pointer`, not an `array`. You are telling: give me the size of a pointer divided by the size of an `int` (which in most systems is 8/4 = 2).

Comment: I would suggest that you add third member variable on your struct where you store the element count.

Comment: If the number of pages pointed to by `new->pages` can vary, and you need to keep track of that number, you can add a member to your `struct Query` to store it.

Comment: To avoid duplication of types, consider writing the seond allocation as `new->pages = malloc(4 * sizeof *new->pages);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.

`sizeof(new->pages)` in

```
int size = sizeof(new->pages)/sizeof(new->pages[0]);
```

doesn't return the total number of `int` elements. Just the size of the int pointer (`int*`). Since `sizeof(int*)` is 8 and `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform, it returns 2.

By the way, you should use `size_t` for `size` as `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` and `%zu` is the format specifier (in `printf()`) to print `size_t`.

Comment: Can't `sizeof(int*)` be 4 and `sizeof(int)` 2 on their platform from what we know?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but very unlikely on any decent compiler used these days(unless it's the outdated Turbo C compiler). In theory, it's even valid to be 16 and 8 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this because the `sizeof` operator yields the size of the type of its operand in bytes, and the type of `new->pages` is a pointer to integer, as defined by the struct, so it evaluates to the size of the pointer, rather than the array.

Note the difference by the example:

```
int arr[4] = {0,1,2,3};
int *p = arr;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr)); // prints 16
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(p)); // prints 4
```

The convention of getting number of elements of an array using `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` works ONLY on arrays, it does not work on pointers, you have to keep track the length on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer are not arrays.Despite the fact that the pointer can point to an array,applying the `sizeof()` operator on a pointer returns the size of pointer,not the size of the array that it points to.

So,in order to keep track of the size,i recommend that you use a variable of type `size_t` to store the value (size).

Oh yeah,and don't name any of your variables `new` in case you want to use a c++ compiler!

```
struct Query {
    int *pages;
    int currentpage;
};

size_t size = 4;

struct Query *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Query));

p->pages = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```